# Cron job doesn't work

Tags: linux, bash, shell, python, cron

I have a shell script which I want to run as a cron-job every 10 minutes. I'm adding the job as follows

```
crontab -e

*/10 * * * * /bin/sh /home/tool/fill_data/run_script.sh
```

And the run_script.sh contents are as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh
python fill_tool.py
```

run_script.sh's permissions are set to be executable like so:

```
chmod +x run_script.sh
```

In cron logs I can see that the cron ran but the script itself did not execute for some reason. When I run the shell script directly or the python file itself - all works fine.

What could be the problem? Why doesn't the cron job execute the file?

Comment: Cronjobs have different environment. Make sure `python` is in its `$PATH` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted by @choroba in the comments, cronjobs have different environments, which means a different `PATH` variable as well.

To make it work you could do one of two things:

1. Add the following to your cron job file (where you've defined your cron job):

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin
```

Where `/usr/bin/` is the path where the python interpreter is. The example I've given is on Ubuntu 20.04.
You can see where the interpreter is with:

```
whereis python3
```

2. The second thing you could do is get rid of all the unnecessary parts of this cronjob:

Add a shebang to your python script on top:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

Make the python script executable:

```
chmod +x fill_tool.py
```

And then just execute the python script in the cronjob:

```
*/10 * * * * /path/to/fill_tool.py
```

That should also work and is better practice.

Note: You can replace python3 with python/python2 depending on your needs.